# Devise store email for user on separate contact table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise, activeadmin

Currently the default Devise generates a user model with an email, the issue is that this would duplicate data. This is because I'm having a contacts table (which has email on it) and the idea is that every user would have a contact but not all contacts would have a user account.

How do I get ActiveRecord to point to a field on another table for the email, is it possible to have a pointer field that would point/redirect to this other table?

I'm also using ActiveAdmin as the CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  delegate :email, :email=, to: :contact
end
```

Comment: I expect so.  Worth a try.

Comment: In the end I decided to create hook that will synchronise the email values between then user and the contact objects but I will mark this as correct as this seems like it would work as well.